# how to use ExportToExcel dll for creating excel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, dllexport

i am using  ExportToExcel dll.In first iteration my dataset contain below record

```
KeyName English Hindi
Name    engval  hival

And second iteration my dataset conatin below record

KeyName English Hindi
Name    engval  hival
```

i have to create xsl file on run time one by one as below.how to apply the style on it
 that it look like good.

```
hindi.xsl    

KeyName English Hindi
Name    engval  hival

punjabi.xsl

KeyName English panjabi
Name    engval  punjabival
```

**Edit:using GridViewExportUtil**

i am trying to create xsl one by one.below is my logic

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{   

//

****logic here to get the record from db and fill the record into dsexcel***

//
gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel;
gvruntime.DataBind();
string headername = string.Empty;
headername = i+".xls";
GridViewExportUtil.Export(headername, this.gvruntime);  
}
```

in this case only last file is overight to previous one..pls tell me how to resolve it

Comment: Check out this site [http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/export-data-to-excel-using-csharp](http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/export-data-to-excel-using-csharp)

Comment: i do not want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?pls let me know another solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, this code will export gridview data to excel. You need to first bind your dataset to gridview then call this function

```
     GridViewExportUtil.Export("hindi.xsl", this.grdhindi);
     GridViewExportUtil.Export("punjabi.xsl", this.grdpunjabi);


// calss code
  public class GridViewExportUtil
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <param name="gv"></param>
        public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    //  Create a form to contain the grid
                    Table table = new Table();

                    table.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

                    //  add the header row to the table
                    if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                    {
                        //gv.HeaderRow.Font.Bold = true;
                        GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                        table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
                    }

                    //  add each of the data rows to the table
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                    {
                        GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    //  add the footer row to the table
                    if (gv.FooterRow != null)
                    {
                        GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow);
                        table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
                    }

                    //  render the table into the htmlwriter
                    table.RenderControl(htw);

                    byte[] s = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", s.Length.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(s);

                    //  render the htmlwriter into the response
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Replace any of the contained controls with literals
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control"></param>
        private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                Control current = control.Controls[i];
                if (current is LinkButton)
                {
                    control.Controls.Remove(current);
                    control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
                }
                else if (current is ImageButton)
                {
                    control.Controls.Remove(current);
                    control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
                }
                else if (current is HyperLink)
                {
                    control.Controls.Remove(current);
                    control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
                }
                else if (current is DropDownList)
                {
                    control.Controls.Remove(current);
                    control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
                }
                else if (current is CheckBox)
                {
                    control.Controls.Remove(current);
                    control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
                }

                if (current.HasControls())
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you can use diffrent way to export griddata to excel

```
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {   


    gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel.Table[i];
    gvruntime.DataBind();
    string headername = string.Empty;
    headername = i+".xls";


 // render the DataGrid control to a file
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\"+headername+".xls"))
    {
        using(HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            gvruntime.RenderControl(hw);
        }
    } 

    }
```

Comment: i am getting error "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of th"

Comment: when it's coming, while debug the code? show me your code how you are using the function

Comment: for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{   

//logic to get the record and set to dsexcel

 gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel;
                    gvruntime.DataBind();
                    string headername = string.Empty;
   
                   
                             headername = i+".xls";
                            
                        
                        GridViewExportUtil.Export(headername, this.gvruntime);  
}

Comment: getting the error on this line= HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

Comment: please use HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); in place of HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

Comment: i have tried but only last xsl file is creating?i want to create both.pls let me know how to solve it

Comment: last file is creating means that code is working. Now you need to check that how you are passing the parameter to function an calling it. Please add your code to you question to find out exact problem.

Comment: this line is causing problem in your code gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel. Please replace it with gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel.Table[i];

Comment: no its not a problem every time i am getting new record in dataset.so always dataset will conatin table1

Comment: It is not 1 (one) it is english character 'i'. gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel.Table[i]; It will change with your loop like gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel.Table[0],gvruntime.DataSource = dsExcel.Table[1]

Comment: try to understand,the problem is not in  dsExcel.Table[0] or  dsExcel.Table[1],i am executing the for loop twice and every time i am getting fresh record into dataset.just try to excute my scenario.you will get same issue. GridViewExportUtil.export()function overwriteing

Comment: you need to remove code for fetching data from database within the loop. Why you need to fetch record in loop from database. Simple first fill the dataset then pass the all table of dataset in for loop to create excel

Comment: when i am using   HttpContext.Current.Response.End() then it's creating first xsl file but when i am using HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();then its's create only last xsl,i mean overwrite the privious one

Comment: Hi, if you have not done this please check my updated answer.

Comment: hi sanin pradeep,i have gone through your approach and finally i got my scenario. thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: If you finds that answer solves your problem then please mark as accept so that other can pick this answer.